# How to ensure binary boolean operators handle const-ness of their arguments correctly?

Tags: c++, class, operators, constants, this

I'm learning C++ and I have problems understanding why I get the following error:

```
mst.cpp:27:15: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const State*’ to ‘State*’
```

The code related is

```
class State {
  size_t _node;
  double _dist;
public:
  State( size_t aNode, double aDist ) : _node{aNode}, _dist{aDist} {}
  inline size_t node() const { return _node; }
  inline double dist() const { return _dist; }
  inline bool operator< ( const State& rhs ) { return _dist < rhs.dist(); }
};
```

and the offending line (27) is the last line of this class declaration. Why does the code try to perform a conversion from const to non-const `State*`? Shouldn't they be treated the same given we are not trying to change anything? Also, given that the const-ness clearly matters, what is the best way to ensure the example works as desired without that error?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code causing problems? The code given does not match the error.

Comment: On a side note, `_node{aNode}, _dist{aDist}` should be `_node(aNode), _dist(aDist)` instead.

Comment: Because `_node` and `_dist` are not complex/array types. Use parenthesis when initializing the value of simple-typed members, not brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my psychic guess:
You're using Microsoft Visual Studio, and you showed us the error in the "Error Window".  Go To View->Output to see the full compiler output, which should have hundreds of lines of gory details about exactly what the error is.

Continuing guessing mode, you're storing these `State` objects in a `set` or maybe you're `sort`ing them.  Whatever you're doing, something is attempting to use `operator<` of your object, with two `const` objects.  Unfortunately:

```
inline bool operator< ( const State& rhs )        { return _dist < rhs.dist(); }
                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

The `operator<` can only be called if the left side is not `const`.  Add a `const` where I've marked, and that should probably solve the issue.  To avoid this issue, and for other neat reasons, the normal way to declare Boolean functions is via friend functions like so (still inside the class):

```
friend bool operator<( const State& lhs, const State& rhs )
{ return lhs.dist() < rhs.dist(); }
```

Since the function is defined right there in the class, the `inline` keyword is not needed here, or for any of the functions you listed.

Comment: Nice "psychic guess" :-)

Comment: HA! I just read your answer.  Why'd you delete it?

Comment: Because I did not make the crucial "psychic" guess about that other spot in OP's code where the operator `<` is used.